# javascript - how to convert unicode string to ascii

Tags: javascript, unicode, ascii

How to convert unicode string to ascii to make a nice string for a friendly url?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626792/converting-uto-u-in-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/javascript-equivalent-of-xpaths-translate

Comment: and google for "transliteration"

Comment: Replacing accented characters doesn't answer this question.  Characters like ㏒ (log), ‰ (per mille), € (Euro), ␀/␆ (nul/ack), ♻ (recycle), ∴ (therefore) remain unaffected by any accented letters becoming unaccented, yet are still not nice friendly url characters until they are replaced by url-safe ascii.  This question is much, much broader than that one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is only a [short list of characters](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html#percent-encoding) that can be safely carried through in a path component of a URL.

```
unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
```

All the other characters will have to be either removed (if you're creating a "slug") or escaped.

Removal can be done with the regex `/[^a-zA-Z0-9-._~]/`.

Escaping can be done with `encodeURIComponent()`.

If you wish to achieve an equivalent of ICONV transliteration (that is, turning `é` into `e` and `€` into `EUR`), you'll have to do your own, although you can [leverage existing solutions](http://dense13.com/blog/2009/05/03/converting-string-to-slug-javascript/) and perhaps transform a [transliteration table](http://mail.nl.linux.org/linux-utf8/2000-10/msg00072.html) to JS format.

Comment: Worked for me! Easy compared to other methods, too.