# javascript escape problem with unicode characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, escaping

I use the following jquery code to load some date on a specific event from external file:

```
$("#container").load("/include/data.php?name=" + escape(name));
```

if the javascript "name" variable contains unicode characters it sends some encoded symbols to data.php file, something like this: **%u10E1**

How can I deal with this encoded symbols? I need to convert them back to readable one.

When I remove the escape function and leave just "name" variable the code doesn't work any more...

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this manually, then you should be using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), not [escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_Functions) (which is deprecated)

The jQuery way, however, would be:

```
$("#container").load("/include/data.php", { "name": name });
```

Either way PHP should decode it automatically when it populates `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

[javascript - how to convert unicode string to ascii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028022/javascript-how-to-convert-unicode-string-to-ascii)